# Java: Creating an array of Integer arrays using generic class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, iterator, queue

The following represents the code of a generic Queue class. Now, what I tried to do in the main, I tried to create an array of Integer arrays, using the Queue class. However, I have failed miserably in my attempt, due to the fact that I have not managed to properly add the elements in the array of Integer arrays to the queue.
Here's the code with some explanations:

The main:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main 
    {public static void main(String[] args)
        {Queue <Integer[][]> Q= new Queue<Integer[][]>(); // creating the queue
        Integer []i1={1,2,3};
        Integer []i2={1,2,3};
        Integer [][]i=new Integer[][]{i1,i2}; // creating the array of integer arrays
        Q.add(i);

        for(Iterator<Integer[][]> it=Q.iterator(); it.hasNext();){ System.out.print(it.next()+" "); }
        System.out.println();

        Iterator<Integer[][]> it=Q.iterator();
        it.next();
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(Q);

        }
    }
```

And here is the Queue class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Queue <T> 
    {LinkedList<T>queue=new LinkedList<T>();
    public void add(T x){ queue.add(x); NOF++; } // the regular add function

    public void add(T[][] x) // the add function in case we get an array of Integer arrays
        { int i=0,j=0,k=0; T [] v; 
        while(x[i][j]!=null) // checking if the are still availabe arrays
            { v=x[i][j]; //1 passing to v an array (or at least what I thought I'd pass)
                                         //but i don't think it works
            while(v[k]!=null)   // while the arrays has elements, add them to the queue
                { queue.add(v); 
                j++;  
                NOF++;
                k++; }
            j++; } }


    public void remove(T x){ queue.remove(); }
    public T peek(T x){ return queue.peek(); }
    public String toString(){ String S=""; for(T x: queue)S=S + x + " "; return S; }
    static int NOF=0;

    public class QueueIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
        { int index=0;
        public boolean hasNext(){ return index < queue.size(); }
        public T next(){ return (T) queue.get(index++); }
        public void remove(){ if(index>0)queue.remove(index-1); } } 

    public Iterator<T> iterator(){ return new QueueIterator<T>(); }

    }
```

So it obviously doesn't work, but I don't understand why, at //1 I get the error:

> Type mismatch, cannot convert from T to T[]

but I don't understand why, x[i][j] was supposed to be T[] as well.

Any ideas, homies?

Comment: Hint: there is **no** need to reduce your variables names to length 1. But a zillion good reasons to not do that.  What I mean is: in your misguided efforts to make your class "short" in the number of lines, you creates something that is extremely hard to read for "normal" java people. You know, there are java coding styleguides, and you are violating them all over the place.

Comment: @GhostCat I've been known to frequently do that ;)

Comment: its the other way around, `v` is declared to be `T[]`  2 lines earlier but  `x[i][j]` resolves to `T` as you expect.

Comment: @George Then seriously: work on that. This is nothing to be proud of! One of the **primary functions** of code is ... to be read! And just to make sure that you really get that: you want us to spent our time to help you. Don't you think it would be helpful for **everybody** here if you would put up code that is easier to digest?!

Comment: The way you right code is really sucky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple (kinda surprising giving the overly complex coding style!)

It seems that you want to create a Queue that *implicitly* works with two-dim arrays of T:

```
class Queue<T> ...
  public void add(T[][] x)
```

But then you are instantiating that thing ... again with two-dim array:

```
Queue <Integer[][]> Q = ...
```

In that sense, you are "doubling" things up here.

You could simply change the queue **usage** to

```
Queue <Integer> Q = ...
```

to make things work!

But that would be the wrong solution. You see: you don't need to those array information at all.

Just make your Queue implementation deal with T objects. Using T[][] all over the place doesn't give you **any** value! Nothing in the Queue class code relies on the fact that you expect a two-dim array of T!

Meaning: you would put that information into your client (so, there you would keep saying `Integer[][]`. But then: that would also be wrong: there is **no** point in mixing arrays and collections. Just use `List<Integer>` or maybe `List<List<Integer>>` if you really need two dimensions.

EDIT:

A) first suggestion ... to fix your problem, turn into your Q class and simply remove any [][] you have in there. Then you can keep your Main class as is, and things should compile.

B) but then, you should consider changing your Main class, too - to make it use Lists instead of arrays!

Comment: I'm sorry man, but I couldn't quite follow you. So I should delete the whole second add method because it's bad code, but what should I replace it with, I didn't quite understand.

Comment: but if I do that, I still get the error: Type mismatch, cannot convert from T to T[]

Comment: The problem is: In order to really help then, you would need to put up the code that you are dealing with now; together with the full error message. You can either un-accept here; and try to rewrite your question; or you might try a new question - probably **after** turning to the helpcenter and reading about minimal, viable examples. Your choice.

Comment: Welp, the code is the one that is already posted, I just replaced the Integer[][] with Integer in main. And after doing so and not changing anything else, in the add function at queue class, where i wrote "//1" i get the error " Type mismatch, cannot convert from T to T[]  "

Comment: @George In order to help you out, I put up *another* answer just with source code that compiles .... following the idea to *not* at all use arrays. But to be precise: you could as well use arrays instead of lists in my example!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Queue<Integer[][]>`, but then you have an add for `T[][]`, which would be `Integer[][][][]`. When using generics here `T` is `Integer[][]`.

If you're wanting to achieve adding multiple individual elements, then you would be looking at accepting an array (or varargs) of `T`, and have your `T` be something like `Integer[]`:

```
public void addAll(T... values) {
    //add all from values
}
```

Lastly you should format your code consistently so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to separate things, here is a version that compiles nicely:
I has two special add methods, one taking a List of T, and the other one taking List of List of T.

And I ran it through the eclipse formatter ;-)

I also removed the NOF counter, as I am pretty sure: you could query that internal queue object about that!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Queue<T> {
LinkedList<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();

public void add(T x) {
    queue.add(x);
} // the regular add function

public void addAll(List<T> xes) {
    queue.addAll(xes);
} // for adding multiple values

public void addAllTimes2(List<List<T>> xesTimes2) {
    for (List<T> xes : xesTimes2) {
        addAll(xes);
    }
} // for adding multiple values

public void remove(T x) {
    queue.remove();
}

public T peek(T x) {
    return queue.peek();
}

public String toString() {
    String S = "";
    for (T x : queue)
        S = S + x + " ";
    return S;
}

public class QueueIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    int index = 0;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < queue.size();
    }

    public T next() {
        return queue.get(index++);
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (index > 0) queue.remove(index - 1);
    }
}

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new QueueIterator();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> Q = new Queue<>(); // creating the queue

    List<Integer> i1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> i2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    Q.addAll(i1);
    List<List<Integer>> i = Arrays.asList(i1, i2); // creating the array of integer arrays
    Q.addAllTimes2(i);
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = Q.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    Iterator<Integer> it = Q.iterator();
    it.next();
    it.remove();
    System.out.println(Q);

}
}
```